# 500 internal server error (working on ubuntu)

Tags: apache-2.2

I copied my printenv.pl file into */usr/lib/cgi-bin* and ran:

```
chmod +rx printenv.pl
```

In my *apache2.conf* file, I added the following lines:

```
<Files ~ "\.pl$">
    Options +ExecCGI
</Files>

AddHandler cgi-script .pl
```

And restarted the Apache server:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

But when I go to http://localhost/cgi-bin/printenv.pl I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Here's my error log file:

```
[Thu Jul 28 19:28:43 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl' failed
[Thu Jul 28 19:28:43 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: printenv.pl
```

But this is what my */usr/lib/cgi-bin* directory looks like:

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 331 2011-07-28 19:01 printenv.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 335 2011-07-28 18:50 printenv.pl~
```

Can you please help me fix this... thanks!

Comment: Can you add the contents of that file to your question?  Seems like it's having trouble running it.

Comment: hi Shane, here's the code:

#!usr/bin/perl 
## ##  printenv -- demo CGI program which just prints its environment 
## use CGI qw(:standard escapeHTML);
 $| = 1; 
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n"; 
foreach $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) 
{     
$val = $ENV{$var};     
$val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;     
$val =~ s|"|\\"|g;     
print "${var}=\"${val}\"<br>\n"; 
}

Comment: Leading slash in interpreter's path is missing, replace **#!usr/bin/perl** with **#!/usr/bin/perl**

Comment: did that, still no difference. is there a series of steps i should follow in a specific order bcoz I could try to do the whole thing all over again

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the first line of your script.

If the line does not begin with `#!` or perl is installed in a different location than the path following the `#!` (e.g., `/usr/local/bin/perl` vs `/usr/bin/perl`), you will get that error.

If the path to perl appears correct, and you've copied over the script from a Windows machine, you may be being tripped up by a carriage return character at the end of the line.

You can use `cat -v /usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl | head -1` to verify that there isn't a `^M` at the end of the line.

If there is, you can use `perl -pi.bak -e 's/\r+$//' /usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl` to remove it.

Comment: hi Kanji, I double checked the path to perl and it is correct. I used the cat function and there isn't a ^M. here's the output of the cat:                                                         cat -v /usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl | head -1
#!usr/bin/perl

Comment: Is that a straight cut and paste? If so, you are missing a `/` before `usr`. If it isn't, are you able to run the script directly from the shell?

Comment: yes indeed, I ran it from the shell and it executes fine, here's the beginning of the output from that :   Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

COLORTERM="gnome-terminal"<br>
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE="ubuntu"<br>
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-WtKdwSEdHu,guid=49985f2d6dfd6826a291778300000015"<br>
DEFAULTS_PATH="/usr/share/gconf/gnome.default.path"<br>
DESKTOP_SESSION="gnome"<br>
DISPLAY=":0"<br>